# turning list into dataframe column in R function

Tags: r, function

I have a function of the (very simplified) form below.

```
doThing <- function(df){
  result <- c() #Sets up dataframe to store lists
  totals <- rowSums(df) #Creates rowsum list from df column
  result[1] <- totals #intended to make totals a column in result. does not work
}
```

How do I assign the list created in this function to a column in my result dataset? I've also tried the following use of the assign function, to no avail

```
assign(result[1], totals)
```

Thank you all!

Comment: `result <- data.frame()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign a row-wise sum as a new column to dataframe.

```
doThing <- function(df){
  transform(df, total= rowSums(df))
}

doThing(mtcars)
#                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb total
#Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.62 16.5  0  1    4    4   329
#Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.88 17.0  0  1    4    4   330
#Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.32 18.6  1  1    4    1   260
#Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.21 19.4  1  0    3    1   426
#Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.44 17.0  0  0    3    2   590
#...
#...
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
 doThing <- function(df) {
     df[["total"]] <- rowSums(df)
     df
 }
 doThing(mtcars)
```